# Drop-down menu: position children links depending on its parent position

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking to solve quite a buggy issue I have with a menu. I've tagged this with jQuery, too - I'm thinking it can solve the issue faster.

I have a drop-down menu, made in CSS, with inner children. Unfortunately, I don't know how many children links each parent may have and each of it left floated and block. I can't edit the CSS each time there's a new link added to add margin-left.

jsFiddle with the menu: http://jsfiddle.net/guBwZ/1/

What I'm after: I'm trying to display the inner links of Link #2 (also Link #3) right below the Link #2, somehow centered (see below jsFiddle).

jsFiddle with what I'm after: http://jsfiddle.net/6meU8/ (hover on Link #2 and Link #3).

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

UPATE:

Based on @craniumonempty example, I've updated the below jsFiddle with what I was looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/guBwZ/32/

Basically, I've moved from display:none to visibility:hidden to measure the width of inner UL and then move it inside the div.center.

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, here's what I got from trying jquery on the given code. You can't really get the location of the elements, because of the way they are set. At least I can't figure it out (I even tried to get the location of the "a" tags). I think it might save you a lot of trouble to separate the drop down elements from the initial menu list and place them underneath according to their location. I was going to use pos and width, but noticed that you have width way off the page as well. Maybe you should make the page tighter in the background, so you can work with it better.

Comment: had to leave for a bit. Hope you solved it yourself, but if you didn't, check below. If you did solve it yourself, please post as an answer and accept it, so people can see the solution.

Comment: You don't need to use a `nomarginright` class. A better way would be to pretend you're using a `nomarginleft` class (`margin: 0 0 0 36px;` on `#menu ul li`), but instead select the first `<li>` element using the [`:first-child`](http://caniuse.com/#search=first-child) selector so you don't have to add any additional classes. This should help make it easier to add/remove nav items.

Comment: @Wev: Good point, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first remove the div with the center. I'm not sure it's even in a place it's supposed to be either way.

Next: put "position:relative;" for "#menu ul li" that will line them up.

Then: remove height and width for "#menu ul li.sub-menu ul"

http://jsfiddle.net/guBwZ/12/

Is that kind of what you are looking for?

Also, if you want examples of multilevel working css menus:

http://ago.tanfa.co.uk/css/examples/menu/hs7.html

EDIT: ok, had to leave for a bit. Not sure where you are currently, but here is what I've got:

http://jsfiddle.net/guBwZ/14/

Not the best code in the world but works. Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").children("ul").children("li").hover(function(){
        var pos = $(this).position();
        var width = $(this).width();
        $(this).children("div.center").each(function(index){
            $(this).css("display","inline");
            var count = $(this).children("ul").children("li").length;
            var left = (pos.left+width/2)-((width*count)/2);
            if ( left < 0 ) { left = 0; }
            $(this).children("ul").each(function(index2){
                $(this).css("left",left);
                left += $(this).width();
            });
        });
    },
    function(){
        $(this).children("div.center").each(function(index){
            $(this).css("display","none");
        });
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#" title="#">Link #1</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="#" title="#">Link #2</a>
            <div class="center">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">Link #2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">Link #2-2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="#" title="#">Link #3</a>
            <div class="center">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">Link #3-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">Link #3-2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" title="#">Link #4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="#">Link #5</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="#">Link #6</a>
            <div class="center">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">Link #6-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="#">Link #6-2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nomarginright"><a href="#" title="#">Link #7</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 111px;
}
#menu ul li a {
    font:normal 15px/19px Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#9a9b9d;
    display: block;
    padding: 11px 35px 10px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#menu ul li.active a {
    background:#FFF;
    color:#000;
}

#menu ul li:hover a, #menu ul li:hover div{
    background:#191c1f;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    color:#444;
}

#menu ul li:hover div{
    display:inline;
}

#menu ul li.active:hover a {
    background:#FFF;
    color:#000;
}

#menu ul li div {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    height:25px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:99;
    left:0;
}


#menu ul li div ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:30px;
}

#menu ul li div ul li a {
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
}
```

Comment: No, they don't need to be stacked - they need to continue in the same linear way as the main menu. The div is just a left-over, sorry.

Comment: Thank you! Your 2nd example was what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that each main LI is dynamic in width, but based on your example I've put a working menu as I wanted. You can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/guBwZ/32/